# which version of android is compatable with native admob?

Tags: ionic4

my ionic version is 4.12.0
 and android version is android 6.3.0 
 i try many diffrents version of android with native admob but not working 
 i change to andoid ver 7.0 apk built but when run  my app its crash
 in  android ver  6.3.0 failed to build apk 
error: RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted() in RewardedVideoAdListener

help me with correct version of android or ionic that work with native admob or old ver of native admob

Comment: which version of admob plugin did you use?

Comment: i used version 0.13.0